# Core Data - Same entity in multiple tableviews

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview, core-data

I am using CoreData to store offline data for data loaded from network. The tables are contained in different tabs inside a TabBar and it looks something like this:

Let's say the entity is **car**, its attributes are **color** and **created**. Entity **car** has relationships to other entities like **wheel** and **seats**.
The **created** attribute is the serverside timestamp at time of serverside insertion.

```
TabBarController

Tab 1 - tableview 1 -> (api.example.com/fetchLatest)

Tab 2 - tableview 2 -> (api.example.com/fetchByColor/red)
```

These two tables show slightly different results of the same **car** entity.

- **tableview 1** loads the most recent results from network (i.e. load
  latest 1000 cars ordered by created).
- **tableview 2** loads only results
  from network matching a query (i.e. load first 500 cars where color
  is red).

As of now when table 1 is reloaded/refetched, the entire **car** entity is deleted/re-inserted. 
Currently, Tab 1 has its own fetchedResultsController and predicates and everything works great.

My question is, how should I approach implementing tab 2 **tableview 2**?

Should I create a second entity (adds redundancy, model data around query)? 2 fetchedResultsController on the same entity? Use inheritance? Also note that data that appear in the first tab can appear in the second tab (i.e. one of the 1000 cars loaded in the first tab happens to be red).

My desired result is when rows in **tableview 1** gets deleted/re-inserted **tableview 2** remains intact/as is.

Thank you!

Comment: One entity, two fetchedResultsController would be my choice

Comment: Hm.. Should I have an attribute indicating which car belongs to which tableview? Then alter tableview 1 delete with a predicate so reloading tableview 1 from network only deletes cars with attribute tableview = 1?

Comment: No, keep your model separated from your view related code. Don't create attributes for UI functionality and beside the same car can exist in both tables.

Comment: How would I know which entity belong to which tableview / fetchedResultsController?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use two separate core data stores.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! that made the most sense.

Comment: I don’t understand why you’d want two stores? I agree with Joakim - one store, one entity, two FRC. When you write “deleted/re-inserted”, what exactly do you mean? Does this mean every record for that entity is deleted then added, or do you mean that your table view is simply reloaded?

Comment: Currently every instance of the entity is deleted in tableview 1 when tab 1 is reloaded. With two FRCs I may need something to keep track of the UI since the while the entities in tab 1 and tab 2 are the same (same attributes, etc), they are different in the sense that the offline data corresponds to 2 data api endpoints made with different queries (i.e. last 1000 cars vs only cars in red) . Insert/update/move/delete data in tab 1 shouldn't affect tab 2.

Comment: I am wondering what was the solution that worked the best for this case?